# class html replace string with symbol

Tags: jquery, css, replace

How can i replace a string that contain symbol to a class css?

HTML

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
       <div class="class-one class-two"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

JQUERY

```
p= '@.class-two';

$('#container').find('.class-one' + ReplaceString(p)).css("background-color", "red");

alert(ReplaceString(p)); // \@\.class-two

function ReplaceString (mystring) {
        return mystring.replace( /(:|\.|\[|\]|,|=|@)/g, "\\" );
}
```

Comment: What symbols can the string contain? What's the expected output?

Comment: any symbols in this case contain '@' but anyone in raplace.

Comment: I have no clue what you are trying to ask here. What exactly are you expecting to find in that shown HTML by creating a selector `.class-one\@\.class-two` …?

Comment: i need to show '.class-two'. But i solved this with:
return mystring.replace( /(:|\|\[|\]|,|=|@)/g, "" );

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are struggeling with the `jQuery` selector. 
Your replacement does work fine for me. I just removed the backslashes as replacement:

```
function ReplaceString (mystring) {
        return mystring.replace( /(:|\.|\[|\]|,|=|@)/g, "" );
}
```

Then you have to modify your `jQuery` selector. If you are having more than one class, then seperate them by comma:

```
$('#container').find('.class-one,.' + ReplaceString(p)).css("background-color", "red");
```

Here is the full code I tried. It worked fine for me:

```
p= '@.class-two';

$('#container').find('.class-one,.' + ReplaceString(p)).css("background-color", "red");

function ReplaceString (mystring) {
        return mystring.replace( /(:|\.|\[|\]|,|=|@)/g, "" );
}
```

See the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dnsnx/h3ajdmge/